# Comparing strings with NSPredicate before saving to Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate, reduce

I am trying to perform a string comparison before saving to Core Data.

The string that gets saved to Core Data will contain a list of physical exercises. The string of exercises must only get saved once **regardless of order**.

**Example:**

```
let str1 = "Burpees Rowing Running"
// This is in Core Data

let str2 = "Running Rowing Burpees"
// This is an attempt to save to Core Data. It should *fail* because there is already an exercise set with these exercises - just not in the same order.
```

**My progress:**

```
func checkEntityThenSave(exerciseGroup:String){
    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "SavedExerciseSets")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "upperBody.sortedComponents == %@", exerciseGroup.components(separatedBy: " ").sorted())
    
    request.predicate = predicate
    request.fetchLimit = 1

    do{
        let count = try context.count(for: request)
        
        print("Count - \(count)") // Always evaluates to 0

        if(count > 0){
            // Save to Core Data
        }
        else{
            // Show Alert
        }
      }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

In my code, I am trying to compare the fetched result (string) in Core Data, with the new string I am attempting to save.

My problem is I keep getting 0 - which is causing the save attempt to fail every time.

**How can I compare a string that I am trying to save, with a string that occurs in Core Data?**

Comment: This looks like the result of a not so optimal design, why are the exercises in a string instead of being their own entity?

Comment: If you are not willing to change the design I see no other way than to split the input string and create a Set from the result and then to load _all_ objects from Core Data and in the same way convert the `upperBody` attribute into an array of Set and then check if the first set exists in that array

Comment: SavedExerciseSets contains a few other attributes. upperBody is the only attribute that i need to check before saving the model to SavedExerciseSets. Not sure why I'd need to break it apart into its own entity

Comment: Because it is the right thing to do from a design perspective IMO but you can always go with my other suggested solution or the solution suggested below.

Comment: Is the `SavedExerciseSets` existing in your CoreData really `"Running Rowing Burpees"`? I mean with all the uppercases at the start of each word?

Comment: @Larme Yes. They are all uppercase.

Comment: Has your entity `upperBody` an attribute `sortedComponents`, i.e. a sorted array of strings? If so, your code should work, else not, because SQL cannot decompose and sort string attributes before fetch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `sortedComponents` is of type `String`, perhaps you can try this:

```
let sortedExerciseGroup = exerciseGroup.components(separatedBy: " ").sorted().joined(separator: " ")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "upperBody.sortedComponents == %@", sortedExerciseGroup)
```

But, if your `sortedComponents` is of type `[String]` the code in the question should already work, just make sure that you save to core data the `exerciseGroup` that is already sorted.

Comment: "just make sure that you save to core data the exerciseGroup that is already sorted" That was the key!! Thank you so much @ramacode. I was clearly missing that step :)

Comment: Haha you are welcome! Should have added the save to core data implementation in the question. However, glad you resolve the problem!